# R: problem using emmeans with lme4::glmer object with logit link

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I am trying to fit a mixed-effects model using `lme4`, using logit link transformation. It is a very simple model, where the response `f` is a function of the fixed effect `case` and the random effect `journal`. Both `f` and `case` are binary values, while `journal` can have several integer values.

I am trying this:

```
> m <- glmer(f ~ case | journal, data = d, family = binomial(link = "logit")
```

, which works well enough. The coefficient is also within the range of what I might expect. I want to estimate the marginal means, however, and use the `emmeans` package for this. I get an error though, which I have tried to figure out using ref_grid, but I can't make sense of the output:

```
> emmeans(m, "case")
Error in emmeans(m, "case")
    No variable named case in the reference grid
> ref_grid(m)
'emmGrid' object with variables:
    1 = 1
Transformation: “logit”
```

From the examples I have seen on a number of websites, it should be possible to use `glmer` and `emmeans` together, and the reference grid should contain the formula I used in the model specification. What I am considering is if this is a more fundamental error in my thinking - can I even use this model for the described data? Or are these functions just not compatible anyway?

For a working example, which is not completely similar to my "real" data, but gives the same error, you can use this:

```
> x <- tibble(a = c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0), b = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1), c = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5))
> m <- glmer(a ~ b | c, data = x,family=binomial(link = "logit"))
> ref_grid(m)
> emmeans(m, "b")
```

Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have any fixed effects in your model (except the intercept). Try this: `glmer(f ~ case  + (1|journal), data = d, family = binomial(link = "logit"))`. Now `case` is fitted as a fixed effect.

Comment: Thatnks @COOLSerdash, this certainly works better. I've seen the `(1|effect)` notation elsewhere, but I don't quite understand what it means. But I definitely have something to work further on now.

Comment: `(1|effect)` fits a random intercept for `effect`. [Here](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification) is a good overview of the formulas.